# What do you call someone who is constantly obssessed with spending time with you and constantly wanting to socialise?

Tags: meaning

I know the obvious word would be outgoing, but it gets to the level where you just think their life is just boring because all they want to do is be outside or chill with you 24/7 so I was wondering if there was a proper word to describe a person like that, maybe tedious?

Comment: If it's an overly attached girlfriend, she's *clingy* or *needy*. If it's your annoying little brother, he's a *tagalong*. In the general case, the person *has no life* [of their own].

Comment: Perhaps this person is "in love with you" (?) and needs to learn that your need for "alone time" is different from theirs. Clearly communicate your needs to this person.

Comment: In US slang, someone that is so desperate to be included they let themselves be taken advantage of is called a "Tool".

Comment: To the introvert, someone who is an extrovert also feels this way... So sometimes, it isn't that the person is clingy or needy, per se, but that s/he is extroverted and just likes being around people, particularly friends.

Answer (score 1):

"Clingy" or "needy" (as noted previously) work.  I would use "clinging" as a slightly more formal construction.  English offers a wide range of metaphors for this.  A "limpet" comes to mind, although one could be much more pejorative and colorful.

Answer (score 1):

In British English there's a verb to ***tag along***, which means to join a group that's going somewhere. Sometimes this is used to denote an effort that is unwelcomed by said group. It's defined as such in the Cambridge Dictionary:

> ***tag along:*** to go ​somewhere with a ​person or ​group, usually when they have not ​asked you to go with them: *I don't ​know her, she just ​tagged along with us*

However, this term has started to be used as a noun, i.e. an unwelcome individual is a ***tag-along***.

I can't find a reference book to back up my claim that the term's used in this way, but if you do a search on Google for 'he's a tag along', you'll find many examples in literature. Here's a good one from *The Facts of Life* (2010) by Graham Joyce:

> *'He's nice enough but as far as I can see he's got no work either. He's a **tag-along**, isn't he? Well he's decent enough, but you can't tag along with a **tag-along**.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider, [***cling-on***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=cling-on&oq=cling-on&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0i19l2j0i10i19.2597.6291.0.8273.7.7.0.0.0.0.279.1612.0j3j4.7.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..0.7.1612.tcXEqBIDh1I#q=%22such+a+cling-on%22)

> Klingon: A humanoid species from a galaxy far, far away, which has come to our planet to form relationships with individual humans and refuses to leave, no matter how often it is given hints or flat out told to do so.
>
> *My ex-boyfriend won't stop calling me to "hang out" and talk about how depressed he is. [What a Klingon](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=cling-on&oq=cling-on&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0i19l2j0i10i19.2597.6291.0.8273.7.7.0.0.0.0.279.1612.0j3j4.7.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..0.7.1612.tcXEqBIDh1I#q=%22what+a+cling-on%22). Yeah, with a 'c.' Cry me a river*. [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clingons)
>
> *[**Cling-ons**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22cling+ons%22&biw=539&bih=354&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdiq6FvdfKAhWJSBQKHWHlCFYQ_AUIDCgG) seek the consistent, reliable attention of their partners in order to make up for what was not present in their upbringing. Even a mean person can fit the bill*. [Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=pgKDYNx9aHIC&pg=PT45&dq=%22cling+ons%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi69b7HttfKAhWJThQKHcl-DU04ChDoAQgcMAA#v=onepage&q=%22cling%20ons%22&f=false)